# Resize div to fit content (image) after resizing content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, percentage, shapes

This seems to be a tricky one :).

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xhrkLwwL/2/ and there a description with some pseudo-code (accurate code in fiddle):

```
<div id="gridSettings" style="height:100%">
    <div id="gridSmaller" style="height:100%">
        <img id="gridSmallerImg" style="height:200%"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make responsive square icons based on height and css only.

Theory is following:

I have a square icon image (200x400px - two in one for hover purposes).
Image is inputed into html as `<IMG>` (NOT as css background property). The `<IMG>` has it's wrapper `DIV` and `<IMG>` is se to height:200%. I am expecting the `IMG` to scale so that I can see only top 50% and the width of the `DIV` to be determined by the width of `IMG`, which is same as the visible height (50% of total height) -> since the image is 200x400px... there you go... a SQUARE :).

Practice:

It works until I resize window. Height of the icon-wrapping `DIV` is 10% of window height, so if I resize window, `DIV` height goes as well, and so does the `IMG` inside. BUT the `DIV's` width stays the same as before resizing and so my icons get clipped :(. If I then change any css prop (via FF DOM Inspector, hover event...), the `DIV` updates to correct width.

Does anyone have any idea, what could be causing it?

Thank you very very much :)

PS: No need for you to send me JS solution. If neccessary I can write my own.

Comment: This appears to be a browser rendering but more than anything else.

Comment: That's a valid note. Strange thing is that all (FF, IE, Chrome, Opera) behave the same. And in DOM Inspectors the pixel size in box visualization is updated after "hover event" as well - but maybe that is how inspectors work.

Comment: What about using `display:inline-flex;` instead of `display:inline-block;` for your `.gridSettingsItem` class. And with js (window resize) get the initial height and width of the items, and then the current height (with window dimensions having changed) and then set the width using the ratio from currentHeight/initialHeight ?

Comment: Actually `inline-flex` solves the issue, only thing to worry about is compatibility. Otherwise I wanted to stay away from JS, but if not, then it would be easier to get the height on resize event and set the width the same.

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html - uses aspect ratio 1:1 and others

Comment: @BootstrapThemer thanks, but I need the oposite - square based on height.